# Finding the DropTarget using jqxListBox's DragDrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jqxwidgets

I need my interface to 'return' during a dragEnd event if a user drags an object from one listbox to nowhere.

My interface consists of a jqxWindow with a sourcing jqxListBox of objects and a jqxpanel that consists of 1..n jqxListBox targets.  In the case of having only one target jqxListBox, the panel is 1/3 empty, so the user can possibly drag an object onto an area without a jqxListBox.

I am using the dragEnd event as an update to my server application when objects are dragged between lists.

Utilizing jQuery core 2.3.1 and jQWidgets 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I posted my question in the jQWidgets forums and was able to get a response.  To get the drop target element from *dragEnd's* event object:

**event.args.dropTargetElement**

Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem because my application is utilizing an older version of jQWidgets (v4.5.1 April, 2017).  I was directed to use as a workaround:

**event.args.originalEvent. X, Y Coordinates**

[listBox drag/drop target discussion](https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/listbox-dragdrop-target/)